# WHy doesn't my stored procedure work for same dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Why doesn't my stored procedure work when I pass same dates (i.e. From and To dates are same) although I have records for these dates but it doesn't. Why ?

```
 SELECT
     Audits.pk_Audits_AuditID, 
     Audits.fk_WebUsers_Audits_UserID, 
     Web_Users.Name as UserName, 
     Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID,
     Districts.DistrictName, 
     Orgs.pk_Orgs_OrgID, Orgs.OrgName, 
     Audits.AuditsUserActivity, 
     Audits.AuditsUserIPAddress,
     Audits.AuditsUserSystemMacAddress, 
     CONVERT(varchar, Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime, 113) AS AuditSystemEntryDateTime
FROM 
    Audits
INNER JOIN
    Web_Users ON Web_Users.UserID= Audits.fk_WebUsers_Audits_UserID
INNER JOIN
    Orgs ON Orgs.pk_Orgs_OrgID= Web_Users.fk_Orgs_OrgID_WebUsers
INNER JOIN
    Districts ON Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID= Orgs.fk_Districts_Orgs_DistrictID
WHERE
    CONVERT(varchar, DateAdd(DAY, -1, Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime)) >= @FromDate
    AND CONVERT(varchar, Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime) <= @ToDate
```

Comment: Remove `CONVERT(varchar..` when you want to compare dates

Comment: Please provide an example with values for `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Well, you're comparing that  `AuditSystemEntryDateTime` - 1 day is bigger or equal to the same day that it is supposed to be smaller than equal to... How is that ever supposed to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your `AuditSystemEntryDateTime` presumably has a time.  I suspect you want the logic as:

```
 Where CONVERT(date, DateAdd(DAY, -1, Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime)) >= @FromDate and
       CONVERT(date, Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime) <= @ToDate
```

In general, you don't want to convert `datetime` to a characters for any purpose other than output.

But, a better way to write this logic is:

```
where Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime >= dateadd(day, 1, @FromDate) and
      Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime < dateadd(day, 1, @ToDate)
```

By keeping all the functions on the constants, SQL Server can use an index for the `where` clause.  Hmmm, the adding of one day would also explain why you get no results.  Perhaps you simply want:

```
where Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime >= @FromDate and
      Audits.AuditSystemEntryDateTime < dateadd(day, 1, @ToDate)
```

This really makes the most sense.

Comment: The last code example should work perfectly if, let's say `@fromDate = @toDate = 2016-02-02` for example

Comment: God damn someone downvoted SQL guru. Upvoted to nullify it. Answer is perfectly valid

Comment: @VR46 . . . I am occasionally wrong and deserve downvotes (well, I don't donwvote myself, so I prefer comments instead).  However, this answer seems to be correct.

Comment: @StackyFlowy Not working is not much to go on.  Provide sample data.  Voting to close.  If you provide sample data to reproduce the problem I will retract my vote to close.